# How to set posts_per_page in order to increment search display results?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

First of all I am working on a theme created by another developer and I am having a few problems understanding at all how theme works or what dev did. So, I am need to increment search display results from 10 to 25. Using a DEBUG plugin I am able to see the query being executed from WP:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%noticias%')
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%noticias%'))) 
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'esp-publicitarios', 'opinion', 'especiales', 'portadadeldia', 'clasificados', 'anunciantes', 'logos')
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_author = 4
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

What I want to change is the `LIMIT` from 10 to 25 so I tried to add this at `functions.php` file at the end:

```
function change_wp_search_size($query)
{
    if ($query->is_search)
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 25; // Change 25 to the number of posts you would like to show
    return $query; // Return our modified query variables
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size'); // Hook our custom function onto the request filter
```

But didn't work since I still getting 10 results. I have tried also set `posts_per_page` in `search.php` file as follow:

```
// Just below get_header() call
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page', 25);
```

And again, same result just 10 items for display. It's possible to extends|increment the max amount of items shown in search query results? any clue or advice?

Comment: Have you check setting in admin >> setting >> reading where it has set ''Blog pages show at most'. Try to change value there and see result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your problem, but the query as it stands seems a bit illogical to me.

Something like this seems more plausible...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.ID
                      FROM wp_posts p
                     WHERE 1=1 
                       AND (
                           p.post_title LIKE '%noticias%' 
                           OR  
                           p.post_content LIKE '%noticias%'
                           )
                       AND p.post_type IN ( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'esp-publicitarios'
                                          , 'opinion', 'especiales', 'portadadeldia'
                                          , 'clasificados', 'anunciantes', 'logos')
                       AND (
                           p.post_status = 'publish'
                           OR (
                              p.post_author = 4
                              AND 
                              p.post_status = 'private'
                              )
                           )
                       ORDER 
                          BY p.post_date DESC
                       LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Don't ask to me, this is what WP is executing when I search some term I don't know where that query comes from and yes look ambiguous to me, in order to clarify that what you need from me?

Comment: I'm looking at `functions.php` and not a clue for where that query is setup, any clue?

Comment: Actually, as this fiddle demonstrates, (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/8814) your query gets evaluated 'correctly', so possibly best to leave it alone. I'll delete my answer shortly so that people don't think this is 'answered'